# Anchor won't work in Chrome but does work in Mozilla

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am stuck with a problem with my nav bar. While clicking on the MENU option, nothing happens but if I right click on them and open them in a new tab they work fantastically. The thing is it's working in Mozilla but not in Chrome

What should I do?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top custom-navbar" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">

        <!-- navbar header -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">New Event</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li> <a href="#intro" class="smoothScroll">Intro</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#overview" class="smoothScroll">Overview</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#speakers" class="smoothScroll">Speakers</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#program" class="smoothScroll">Programs</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#register" class="smoothScroll">Register</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#venue" class="smoothScroll">Venue</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#sponsors" class="smoothScroll">Sponsors</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>


<!-- =========================
    INTRO SECTION   
============================== -->
<section id="intro" class="parallax-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <h3 class="wow bounceIn" data-wow-delay="0.9s">July 22 - 26 in San Francisco, CA</h3>
                <h1 class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="1.6s">Web Design Conference</h1>
                <a href="#overview" class="btn btn-lg btn-default smoothScroll wow fadeInUp hidden-xs" data-wow-delay="2.3s">LEARN MORE</a>
                <a href="#register" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger smoothScroll wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="2.3s">REGISTER NOW</a>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Did you include the needed javascript files?

Comment: Yes i did. All the JS  and Jquery too

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: are there any errors on console on anchor click..?

Comment: I dont think so.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just take a wild guess and assume you're using Bootstrap.

Make sure to include the bootstrap.js and jquery.js in the correct order:

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Make sure to include jquery before your bootstrap.js file, this should do it.

For me, it's working in [this fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/8rv5y525/)

Comment: http://www.free-css.com/free-css-templates/page221/new-event Here is the link to the Web. Please have a look

Comment: This is working for me. Try to reload the page using Ctrl + F5, this will clear your cache. I don't know what else would be the problem. For me, this is working fine in Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

Comment: Heres the sequence please see 1 . <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
2 <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
3 <script src="js/jquery.parallax.js"></script>
4<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
5 <script src="js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
6 <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
7 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: I've loaded your code sample and it seems to work fine for. I did not change anything.

Comment: It does not please check the link

Comment: I did check the link. Please explain again what's not working for you because everything you described works fine for me.

Comment: Ya he's not crazy. It's doing it for me too. Works in IE, but not Chrome (Shocker).

Answer (score 0):

Within `js/smoothscroll.js`, you have two dependencies:

- jQuery.scrollTo
- jQuery.localScroll

The issue seems to be with these plugins (possibly outdated?). `localScroll` calls `e.preventDefault`, however `jQuery.scrollTo` is not properly scrolling to the element with the corresponding `hash` (the code is minified, and I can't find the source for those versions).

After updating the dependencies, I verified scrolling worked as intended (at least in Chrome).

Steps to resolve:

1. Replace jQuery.scrollTo with:
   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo/master/jquery.scrollTo.min.js
2. And replace jQuery.localScroll with:
   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flesler/jquery.localScroll/master/jquery.localScroll.min.js